# FFMPEG with VP9 + RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, vp9

When we use HEVC + RTSP, ffmpeg works fine. The stream is captured by webcam.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M  -f vfwcap -i "0" -strict experimental -c:v hevc_qsv -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1/live/test
```

The output is like:

```
frame=  355 fps= 37 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.27 bitrate=N/A dup=159 drop=0 speed=1.18x
```

Then we switch to VP9 + RTSP.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M  -f vfwcap -i "0" -strict experimental -c:v libvpx-vp9 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1/live/test
```

The fps and speed looks too slow:

```
frame=  263 fps=9.5 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.94 bitrate=N/A dup=119 drop=0 speed=0.288x
```

Then we use ffplay to play the stream. There are a lot of error messages and the video seems frozen.

```
[vp9 @ 000001c3da86c200] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3dffd5700] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da8477c0] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da848240] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da848e40] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01d2fc0] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01dd280] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01e8980] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01f1880] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da86c200] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3dffd5700] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da8477c0] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da848240] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da848e40] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01d2fc0] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01dd280] Not all references are available0B f=0/0
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01e8980] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01f1880] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da86c200] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3dffd5700] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da8477c0] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da848240] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3da848e40] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01d2fc0] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01dd280] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01e8980] Not all references are available
[vp9 @ 000001c3e01f1880] Not all references are available
```

Finally, we try hardware VP9 encoder.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M  -f vfwcap -i "0" -strict experimental -c:v vp9_qsv -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1/live/test
```

It can't work.

```
[swscaler @ 0000021e88df9fc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] Selected ratecontrol mode is unsupported
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] Low power mode is unsupported
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] Current frame rate is unsupported
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] Current picture structure is unsupported
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] Current resolution is unsupported
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] Current pixel format is unsupported
[vp9_qsv @ 0000021e8687df80] some encoding parameters are not supported by the QSV runtime. Please double check the input parameters.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

So, how can we deal with VP9 + RTSP successfully?

Comment: What CPU are you trying to encode on?  [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) that VP9 hardware encoding is supported since Kaby Lake (7xxx) but the [ffmpeg mailing list](http://www.ffmpeg-archive.org/Is-it-vp9-qsv-encoder-work-on-i9-9900k-CPU-td4690003.html) says it requires Ice Lake (10xxx). I don't know which is correct.

Comment: I'm using Intel i5-8265U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am by no means an authority on this, but I'm in a similar situation to yours.  If I understand [this GitHub issue correctly](https://github.com/intel/media-driver/issues/771), the "gen 9" Intel GPU -- "Kaby Lake, Coffee Lake, Whiskey Lake, Comet Lake" [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video), which I think corresponds to 7xxx through 10xxx -- has hardware support for VP9 encoding, but the Windows drivers do not expose this feature for the Media SDK to take advantage of.  I *think* that the error messages we're seeing reflect the fact that QSV encoding is not available on our particular CPU model, on our OS.

For some reason, the feature *is* available on Linux.  I have seen several sources that say VA API (`vp9_vaapi`) should work on any of these "gen 9" processors; it's possible that the QSV driver (`vp9_qsv`) would work in Linux as well.  I haven't had a chance to try it yet.